# Why my message doesn't write into the socket when I try to read the response after sending it?

Tags: rust, tcp, network-programming

```rust
let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("192.168.56.1:24301").unwrap();

let input = String::from("LISTMON");

let mut buffer = [0; 128];

// Send message to server
stream.write(input.as_bytes()).expect("Erreur lors de l'envoi du message");
stream.flush().expect("Erreur lors du vidage du tampon");

// Read response from server
let n = stream.read(&mut buffer[..]).expect("Erreur lors de la lecture de la réponse");
println!("{:?}", &buffer[..n]);`
```

Here is the code that I made, it sends the message `"LISTMON"` to my server coded in Java (it works perfect, I already did a client in Java and everything works) and my server is supposed to response with a list of available protocols.

The code above doesn't write my message to my server but if I remove the line to read the response it works, am pretty lost. It seems like my program needs to shut down for the message to be sent.

```
let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("192.168.56.1:24301").unwrap();

let input = String::from("LISTMON");

let mut buffer = [0; 128];

// Send message to server
stream.write(input.as_bytes()).expect("Erreur lors de l'envoi du message");
stream.flush().expect("Erreur lors du vidage du tampon");
```

The code above as said writes the message perfectly but I need to read the response as you guess so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: First, use [`write_all`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#method.write_all). When you use `write`, you need to loop until all the bytes are written. Then, the server is probably waiting for you to [shutdown](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#method.shutdown) the write half of the connection after flushing.

Comment: I don't see why the server would not receive the data.

Comment: Show the server code. I suspect you are using `readLine()`, but you aren't sending lines. If so, add a newline to each sent message.

Comment: @user207421 it was just that yes i put a \n and works perfect am dumb sorry ahah.